# print portion of file matching a regular expression on both sides

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

Please help, i have been studying sed, awk, grep command for long time now i could not figure out how to solve this problem. I have a log file in unix, i was to print start from a given regular expression until another expression. FOr example

```
<!--##
[USERID | 2019-10-25 13:07:39,399 | SIBJMSRAThreadPool : 4 | Android-Transactionname-1572023259140 | -]
Request On
Accept: text/xml
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/xml
User-Agent: NNOS-CCF
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1792

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext" soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" soapenv:mustUnderstand="0"
>
<wsse:UsernameToken>
<wsse:Username></wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password></wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>

##-->

<!--##
[USERID | 2019-10-25 13:07:41,264 | SIBJMSRAThreadPool : 2 | Android-Transactionname-1572023260299 | -]
Request On
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 327
```

I want to just output text starting from Android-Transactionname-1572023259140 to ##-->

Comment: read this: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or

Comment: thanks to @P... this link answers my question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-print-lines-between-two-patterns-inclusive-or-exclusive-in-sed-awk-or

Answer (score -1):

If you want to be line-oriented:

```
awk '/Android-Transactionname-1572023259140/,/\#\#-->/'
```